# A time limit for user input

Tags: java

I am having some problems making a small game for myself. The piece of code I am having problems with is a timeout for user input. For example: The game will show a letter on the screen. The user has to enter that letter by a certain time; if they don't, they take damage.  If someone could explain what I could use to fix this problem it would be great.

```
package weapons;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


class wepons {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int weapondamage =0 , health = 0 , hits = 0, potion = 0, beast = 0, beastdmg = 0, letter = 0;
        String weapon;
        ;

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);   

        System.out.println ("please pick a wepon that will kill the boss \n");
        weapon = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        if (weapon.equals("sword")){
          System.out.println("you have picked the sword");
          weapondamage = (int) ((Math.random()*100));
          health = weapondamage*3;
        }


        System.out.println("Sword damage is " + weapondamage);
        System.out.println("Boss health is " + health);
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of hits it will take to kill the boss.");
        hits = in.nextInt();
        if(hits == health/weapondamage) {
        System.out.println("you have killed the boss.The boss had droped a potion.\nYou pick up the potion and drink it!\nYour health has now gone up to 350hp");
        }

        else {

            System.out.print("You have failed to kill the boss");



        }
        potion = (int)350;
        beastdmg = (int) ((Math.random()*60));
        System.out.println("By killing the boss you have awoken the beast!");
        System.out.println("The beast nocks you onto your back");
        System.out.println("The beast will hit you for"+beastdmg+"damage");
        System.out.println("You can block the beast damage by hitting the write key");
        Random r = new Random();
        int c = r.nextInt(26) + (byte)'a';
        System.out.println((char)c);
        letter = in.next().charAt(0);
        if(  letter == ((char)c)){
            System.out.println("You blocked the beast damage");




        }
        else {

            System.out.print("You took damage");



        }
        }




        }  // main
```

Comment: "having problems" doesn't tell us WHAT the problem is... **HOW** is this code not working?

Comment: It would be to your advantage as an asker to remove unnecessary code. Include only the code that pertains to your question (so the code you predict would require a time limit) and then explain any other code in words if necessary. See [sscce.org](http://sscce.org)

Comment: You might want to use [Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) for this

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to do this, I'm answering using the OP's style, in the simplest possible way, so measuring user time to press the letter. Here's a functioning snippet:

```
    System.out.println("You can block the beast damage by hitting the write key");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Random r = new Random();
    int c = r.nextInt(26) + (byte) 'a';
    System.out.println((char) c);
    char letter = in.next().charAt(0);
    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    if (letter == ((char) c) && elapsedTime <=5000) {
        System.out.println("You blocked the beast damage");

    } else {

        System.out.print("You took damage");

    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to take a look at Threads.

With threads, you can execute several processes at once, rather than just linear coding line by line.

For example, you could say:

```
while(health > 0){
   Thread.sleep(5000); //parameter for sleep is milliseconds, so this is 5 seconds
   if(weapon == null){
      health -= damage; 
   }else{ break; }
}
```

The problem with this is that you might need to create a separate class which extends Thread to invoke the damage loss... If the timed aspect is that necessary I would suggest reading up on threads. Don't take this code snipped literally, this is just a basic outline... From my experience with threads you would need to create a method that would return the weapon value, because you want your Thread to check if the user inputed the value for a weapon.

You also may want to refer to this threading tutorial:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html

Comment: `create a separate class which extends Thread to invoke the damage loss` what? why? Never ever ever extend from `Thread`, ever.